# how to maintain connection betwen an android client and a socket server?

Tags: java, android, serversocket

I need to maintain a connection in a java server socket  from my android application. (I'd like to maintain this connection at the android application).
As a temporary solution, I itertatively refresh the connection every 1 or 2 minutes. (I establish a connection between my application and the socket server  every time to guarantee that the connection is maintained)
Is there another solution?

I really need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A Better model is based on push-notifications.

Your android device registers with your server, through the google GCM service (https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Whenever the server had data for your client, it pushes it through GCM.

Using GCM will relieve you from managing a live connection and message delivery guarantee.

If the client has data for the server, it can connect-send-disconnect.

The above model works MUCH better on Android, and is also more battery efficient, more reliable, and less to code. In addition it allows your application to be automatically waken-up when an incoming server message arrives, so you don't have to have a "foreground service" running waiting for messages, taking up phone resources and showing a constant notification.

For keeping a connection using TCP based sockets you should send a keep-alive message every once in a while. If that keep alive message does not get send, you re-establish the connection.
For best results, have the Android client do the keep alive.
In addition, have your Android monitor connection state, so you can know in real time if your connection has gone down, or up.
A typical android device may change from 3G to wifi, lose connectivity underground etc..